# Grep or find to find a pattern

Tags: regex, grep, find

I'm looking through a couple hundred files looking for the following string:

```
$v1=Name($v2[x1].$v3[x2].$v4[x3].$*v5[x4].)

grep -HREln "(x1)" . > foo
find . -type f | xargs grep -l 'x1' > foo
```

However the variable x1 changes from file to file.
What I would like to do is search for the pattern:

```
$*=Name($*[*].$*[*].$*[*].$**[*].)
```

regardless of the variable or white spaces. 
any assistance would be great.

Comment: Take a look: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Change every `*` to `.*`, put `\` before every `$`, `[`, `]`, or literal `.`, and you're there!

```
find . -type f |
  xargs grep -l 'Name(\$.*\[.*\]\.\$.*\[.*\]\.\$.*\[.*\]\.\$.*\[.*\]\.)' > foo
```

Note: this will miss variations that span multiple lines, and does not take whitespace into account at all.